# How do I do full disk encryption on Ubuntu, using a TrueCrypt or VeraCrypt hidden volume?

Tags: ubuntu, truecrypt, veracrypt

I've encrypted a Windows drive using the Windows version of VeraCrypt. It was pretty straightforward.

I have Ubuntu right now, with the VeraCrypt fork of TrueCrypt installed. I don't see any of the same options for full disk encryption?  No luck with Google yet either.

Hows it done on Ubuntu (preferably with a hidden volume)?